# Exponential Function related proof.

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I am trying to learn real analysis by myself and I am totally not getting the proof.Please help me out.I am also reading Analysis 1 by Terence Toa and I did read the chapter about power series but I still did not get why the 1/2 came there.Please help me out.Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous function $f$ will attain a maximum value on every interval $[a,b]$. The specific interval $[0,\frac12]$ just has some nice properties that makes it useful.

Tao uses the Mean Value Theorem, which states that for a differentiable function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$, there exists a $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$

In this specific case, we have $a=0$ and $b=x$, so we have that
$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

for some $\xi\in(0, x)$. But we can simplify this, because $f(0)=0$, to get
$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x)}{x}\implies xf'(\xi)=f(x).$$

Finally, because $f=f'$, we have the chain of equalities $f(x)=xf'(\xi)=xf(\xi)$. We also know that $x\in[0, \frac12]$ because it is, by definition, where $f$ attains its maximum on that interval. Therefore, $0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2}$, and in particular, $x<1$. This gives us that $f(x)\leq xf(x)\leq\frac12f(x)$. Finally, $f(x)\leq\frac12f(x)$ only if $f(x)\leq 0$. But since $x$ is where $f$ attains its maximum on the interval, $f\leq 0$ on $[0, \frac12]$.

Comment: Thank You! I got it!